# Spacing in exponential term in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I got a problem about the spacing between plus sign in `a^{++}`.
If you look the figure below, the spacing is quite large.
I am wondering whether there is a way to make the spacing narrower.

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = plt.gca()

x = np.linspace(0,1,20)

plt.plot(x,x**2);
plt.plot(x,-x**2);
plt.text(0.1,0.7,"$a^{++}$",fontsize=25);
plt.text(0.1,-0.7,"$b^{--}$",fontsize=25);
```

[image]

Comment: Try something like `'$a^{{+}{+}}$'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write code inside `$...$` you are using matplotlib's [MathText engine](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html). With this, spacings are the same as in [usual TeX](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_119.html), such that e.g. `\!` will insert a negative thin space. The more `\!` you use, the closer will be the letters. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = plt.gca()

x = np.linspace(0,1,20)

plt.plot(x,x**2);
plt.plot(x,-x**2);
plt.text(0.1,0.7,"$a^{\!\!\! + \!\!\!\! +}$",fontsize=25);
plt.text(0.1,-0.7,"$b^{--}$",fontsize=25);
```

[image]